# How many treble keys should I have for accordion? - Additional question

Tags: key, keyboard, accordion

I have asked a similar question yesterday. Thanks so much for the answers.
I am a beginner for accordion (have some knowledge on Electronic Organ, and 63 years old now). Particularly, I see a trade-off in selecting whether 26 or 34 treble keys? My friend told me no big difference between them in playing songs, and the 26-key one is smaller and lighter. But I think it has 8 keys (4 white and 4 black) less than the 34-key one. And I am concerning about due to 4 white keys less, the 26-key accordion covers a narrow note range, so it can’t play as many music/songs as a 34-key accordion does, which is different to what my friend said. Appreciated if you could give some more advices on my concern, so that I know which one I should buy.
Thanks,
Steve.

Comment: Your previous question already has answers covering your exact query here. Please read existing answers before writing new questions

Comment: Also, instead of writing thanks under good answers, please just use the upvote button - it's worthwhile reading our [about] page to understand how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which accordion you are looking at, but the 26-key accordions that I see online tend to start at B below middle C. I would find that annoying, but I could transpose to fit (I make my own sheet music). I think a lot of music would have to be adjusted, though, because it's common to go a little lower than that. Going down to G below middle C is common in the music I've seen.

This all depends on how comfortable you are adjusting music to your needs. You could play any song after making adjustments to it by transposing or adapting.

As a beginner, changing a song to fit might be difficult for you. Perhaps a friend or teacher could help, though?